pinescript - weird label results printed on each candle on for loop
I'm trying to label whenever a specific bar pattern is picked up for example 3 straight topping tails. Simple, but my code it shows the labels on the last 50 or so candles which is not the result of what my if loop is filter out:
indicator("Simple 3 topping tail" ,overlay=true)
lbl = label.new(bar_index, na)
float nmax = 200

for n = 0 to nmax
 if open[n+2] > close[n+2]//topping wick on buy candle
  if high[n+2] > open[n+2]
    if open[n+1] > close[n+1]//topping wick on sell candle
      if high[n+1] > open[n+1]
       if open[n] > close[n]
        if high[n] > open[n]//topping wick on a sell candle
         label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index, n)//tag when this pattern is revealed
         label.set_text(lbl, str.tostring(n, ".#"))   
         label.set_color(lbl, color.red)
         label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.abovebar)
         label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)


Is your pattern recognition not working or are you asking why you have 50-ish labels and not more?

Hi it's not recognizing the pattern at all through the iteration. I'm not supposed to get 50 labels. It's simply labeling the last 50 candles.

Well, then you have to debug and see why your conditions are always returning true. You can use log.info() to debug.
